# Icons are not visible after chrome browser update

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg

After the last Google Chrome update (52.0.2743.116 --> 53.0.2785.89/53.0.2785.101) the icons on my WebApp are not visible anymore.

I'm using an SVG spritesheet as background-image and choose the needed icons with background-position in my CSS.

I found out, that the icons are visible if a background-color is given, which is not transparent. For a icon with transparent background I use the value rgba(255,255,255,0.01).

**My HTML:**

```
<h3>background-image with background-position</h3>

<span class="icon icon-1"></span>
<span class="icon icon-2"></span>
<span class="icon icon-3"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

**My CSS:**

```
.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    background-image:url("%FilePATH%/icons_spritesheet.svg");
    background-size: 2350px 2340px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 2px
}

.icon-1 {
    background-position: -285px -645px;
}

.icon-2 {
  background-position: -715px -505px;
}

.icon-3 {
  background-position: -285px -785px;
}
```

Why is this happpening? Other/better solutions are welcome.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION (that worked for me):**

The Problem is my SVG. I used an other file and hadn't this problem.

However... this issue occured on the newest Chrome version and maybe others have the same problem.
For my SVG it worked with removing the border-radius. If a border-radius is given the icons are not visible anymore.